# Why "bgcolor" for "pre" not shown?

Tags: html

I make HTML report - cannot see yellow BG color for report. Why.
Html has code like

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<font name="Courier New" size="3" color="#000">
<pre><code>
<font color="#FF0000" bgcolor="#FFFF00" >1</font>
</code></pre>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

You see here yellow bg for "1".
I use Firefox.

Comment: instead of applying style in html, use CSS

Comment: This example reminds me of Geocities. I can't remember the last time I saw a `<font>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using very outdated HTML notations. The correct markup would be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Courier New", sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #000;
      }
      span {
       background-color: #FFFF00;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Black text <span>with yellow background</span>
  </body>
</html>
```